# Need help in volatile and non volatile concept in implemented java code?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I wrote following code to understand the volatile concept in java but the output seems to be confusing rather than clarifying the concept. Corrections, clarifications and feedback are welcomed and appreciated.

```
package threading;

public class UnSyncRead {
    //volatile static int value = 987;
    static int value = 987;
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ThreadEx4 t = new ThreadEx4(value);
        t.start();
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread( new ThreadEx3(value));
            thread.start();
        }
    }

}

class ThreadEx3 implements Runnable{
private int i;
    public ThreadEx3(int i) {
        this.i=i;
}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+ "  "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+ " inside "+i);
    }



}

class ThreadEx4 extends Thread{
    private int i;
    public ThreadEx4(int i) {
        this.i=i;
    }
    public void run() {
        ++i;
        System.out.println("changed the value to "+i);
    }
}
```

This program gives the following output

```
changed the value to 988
12  Thread-1  inside 987
13  Thread-2  inside 987
14  Thread-3  inside 987
15  Thread-4  inside 987
```

but if I modify the code to make `value` variable `volatile` by doing following change and running the code.

```
public class UnSyncRead {
volatile static int value = 987;
//static int value = 987;
public static void main(String[] args) {


    ThreadEx4 t = new ThreadEx4(value);
    t.start();
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread( new ThreadEx3(value));
        thread.start();
    }
}

}
```

I get following output which is exactly same when I ran it without volatile keyword.

```
changed the value to 988
12  Thread-1  inside 987 
13  Thread-2  inside 987
14  Thread-3  inside 987
15  Thread-4  inside 987
```

My question is why the threads in the for loop are still reading the value of `value` variable as `987` and not `988`, even after implementing volatile keyword.

Will deeply appreciate answer to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with multithreading at all, it is a much more fundamental issue.

```
class ThreadEx4 extends Thread{
    private int i;
    public ThreadEx4(int i) {
        this.i=i;
    }
    public void run() {
        ++i;
        System.out.println("changed the value to "+i);
    }
}
```

You are changing your private variable `i` here, not the global `static` field.

Java passes things around by value. So when you say `new ThreadEx4(myInteger)`, the constructor will receive the number inside of `myInteger`. Whatever it does to its local copy does not affect `myInteger` at all.

To continue your multi-threading experiments, get rid of the local variables and do

```
class Ex4 extends Runnable {
      @Override
      public void run(){
          int newValue = ++UnSyncRead.value;
          System.out.println("changed the value to "+newValue);
      }
}
// and the same for the other runnables
```